# Get some kind of notification on PC when someone calls my iPhone

Tags: windows-10, iphone

I have an iPhone 5s and a Windows 10 PC at workplace. Usually I turn off all sounds on my phone to prevent distraction and not to disturb my coworkers. But often I miss important calls this way.

I'm on my PC staring at the screen for most of the time. Is there a way to get some kind of notification on my pc when someone is calling?

Comment: You can achieve that with IFTTT, there is a lot of applets that either send a email or a IM message. There is also the app [Your Phone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4459358/windows-10-your-phone-app-help) on Windows but it's only available for Android.

Comment: Couldn't find a specific one that does what I need :/ Most of them are related to weather.

Comment: https://ifttt.com/search/query/missed%20calls?tab=connections - maybe that helps?